# Remove field in backend (product - description "in_depth")

Tags: magento

I want to remove the "In depth"-field from the backend. It is now mandatory, so it would be nice, if it wasn't mandatory afterwards.

Thanks for any help in advance,

Flo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a protected attribute. If you really must remove it from being required:

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-delete-system-attribute/

Comment: thanks for the link but i think the question is about just making attribute non-mandatory instead of deleting from database.

Comment: I will leave your link up - even if 'remove' was the wrong word here! Great blog b.t.w. - I am a regular reader, thanks for sharing what you know so well.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make the **in_depth** attribute non-mandatory, then you can simply edit the attribute and set **Values Required** field to "**No**".

Go to

- **Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes**
- Search for **in_depth**
- Edit it
- Change **Values Required = No**